# What is the library name needed to use JObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to use JObject.

The question is where i can find dll for this case and what must to appear in using
i want to write something like:

```
JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are looking for [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) written by [James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/)

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Answer (score 59):

It's in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace.  You should just need the Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this link http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and download it

OR You can you the Nuget command line in the visual studio that will install it for you. If you want to try it here is the command you have to run: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1-beta3